# Programming ATmega using Arduino as ISP

Tags: arduino, atmega, isp

For my systemprogramming class I have to program an ATmega48a µController.

At university we're using an avrmkII to program the chips, but as i don't have such a device at home so I figured I could use my Arduino as an ISP programmer.

Now when I run the avrdude command (see Makefile below) to flash a simple blink program onto the controller I get the following error:

```
avrdude -pm48 -P /dev/ttyACM0 -B19200 -cavrisp -Uflash:w:blink.hex:a -v

avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/user/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0
         Using Programmer              : avrisp
         Setting bit clk period        : 19200.0
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0

avrdude done.  Thank you.

make: *** [Makefile:40: program] Fehler 1
```

But I can't figure out why they are not in sync. All tutorials / questions & answers I found focused on programming the chip using the Arduino IDE which I was specifically told not to use, because the IDE does all the heavy lifting for you.

I know that the ATmega is working because I already programmed it using the avrmkII, and the blink sketch (a different one) that I uploaded then is still able to run.

Electronics:

- ATmega48a
- Arduino Mega 2560

Wiring:

- Arduino pins based on: https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/arduino-isp/ArduinoISP#how-to-wire-your-boards
- ATmega pins based on: [ATmega48 datasheet page 12](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061A.pdf)
- Arduino -> ATmega48a
- 50 -> 18
- 51 -> 17
- 52 -> 19
- 10 -> 1
- 10 µF between GND and RESET on Arduino Mega

software:

- OS: Parrot OS 5.1 (Electro Ara)
- avrdude version 6.3-20171130
- Arduino IDE to upload ISP sketch onto Arduino: 2.2.1

Makefile:

```
TARGET=blink
MCU=atmega48a
SOURCES=blink.c
MCU_dude=m48

PROGRAMMER=avrisp
PORT=-P /dev/ttyACM0
BAUD=-B19200

OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
CFLAGS=-c -Og 
LDFLAGS=

all: hex eeprom

hex: $(TARGET).hex

eeprom: $(TARGET)_eeprom.hex

$(TARGET).hex: $(TARGET).elf
    avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .data -j .text $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).hex

$(TARGET)_eeprom.hex: $(TARGET).elf
    avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .eeprom --change-section-lma .eeprom=1 $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET)_eeprom.hex

$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS)
    avr-gcc $(LDFLAGS) -mmcu=$(MCU) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET).elf

.c.o:
    avr-gcc $(CFLAGS) -mmcu=$(MCU) $< -o $@

size:
    avr-size --mcu=$(MCU) -C $(TARGET).elf

program:
    avrdude -p$(MCU_dude) $(PORT) $(BAUD) -c$(PROGRAMMER) -Uflash:w:$(TARGET).hex:a -v

clean_tmp:
    rm -rf *.o
    rm -rf *.elf

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
    rm -rf *.elf
    rm -rf *.hex
```

I hope I provided all the necessary information needed. if not I'll update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
avrdude -pm48 -P /dev/ttyACM0 -B19200 -cavrisp -Uflash:w:blink.hex:a -v
```

That line contains a crucial error, you need to change -B to -b instead.